# Command RaiseCanExecuteChanged is not fired in Text change event

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm following this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1272407/A-Wizard-Application-in-WPF-with-MVVMC-Navigation) to create a wpf wizard application using MVVMC.
What I want to do is to disable button when the content of textbox is empty. A text change event is added to check user's input. If it is empty, call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` to fire button's `canExecute()`. But the canExecute is not fired.
I tested these code in a wpf user control, it could be fired. But when I move them to MVVMC, it does not work.

Below are code fragment. I upload full project to [repo](https://github.com/kerwenzhang/MVVMC)

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ComputerName}" TextChanged="ComputerName_TextChanged"/>
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}">Test</Button>
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void ComputerName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   viewModel.HandleComputerNameTextChanged(((TextBox)sender).Text);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    private string computerName = "";
    public string ComputerName
    {
        get
        {
            return computerName;
        }
        set
        {
            computerName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    internal void HandleComputerNameTextChanged(string text)
    {
        ComputerName = text;
        TestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public ICommand _testCommand;
    public virtual ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_testCommand == null)
            {
                _testCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                    () =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("test");
                    },
                    () => canGotoNext());
            }
            return _testCommand;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool canGotoNext()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComputerName))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The TextChanged event handler is redundant. Add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the Text Binding in order to get notified about every change of the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` instead of using the`TextChanged` event to fire the Command `CanExecute()`.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ComputerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}">Test</Button>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private string computerName = "";
    public string ComputerName
    {
        get
        {
            return computerName;
        }
        set
        {
            computerName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            TestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```